# How do I write a text formula in NetSuite to change multiple text values to a standardized text value?

Tags: sql, search, formula, netsuite

We use a custom category field to segment our accounts in NetSuite. The name of the field is "cseg3"

I have 4 categories called "Construction Supply", "Equipment Dealer", "Key Account", and "OEM". If it is any of those values I want it to return the text "Rental - Other", if it is none of those values then return the original category.

I tried using the formula below, but it is not working, would anyone have a suggestion on how to build this.

```
Case When {cseg3} = 'Construction Supply' or 'Equipment Dealer' or 'Key Account' or 'OEM' then 'Rental - Other' - else {cseg3} end
```

It doesn't work or returns an error.

Comment: I was able to solve this, below is the answer in case anyone else runs into this issue. Thanks. 

CASE WHEN {cseg3} IN ('Equipment Dealer', 'OEM', 'Construction Supply', 'Key Account') THEN 'Rental Other' ELSE {cseg3} END

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question; please post your comment as an answer.